# Open and close React Material UI Snackbar component programmatically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to programme an SPA in React/Material-UI and I'm having some issues. I've developed a modal login box that is launched from a button on a navbar. When the user presses submit I call a backend api using fetch and depending on the result of the returned status code I want to open a snackbar component with certain information or close the modal login window.

I've learnt to open snackbars by clicking on a link but how can I open one programmically? I also need to close my modal window upon success of the api call and I don't know how to achieve this either. I can also achieve this by manually clicking on a link that is bound to original button on the nav bar.

I've tried using the basic snackbar example from the docs and putting it in a separate component but it only shows how to launch those by clicking on a link that's already in the actual Snackbar functional component. I need to know how to display a snackbar programmatically from another component.

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something obvious :)

**Login.js React Component**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button'
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField'
import CustomizedSnackbars from './CustomSnackbars'

class LoginDialog extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {username: "",
                      password: ""};

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
      <some code>
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const data = {
            "username":this.state.username,
            "password":this.state.password
        }

        fetch("https://mywebsite.com/auth/login", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body:  JSON.stringify(data)
        })
        .then(function(response){
            if (response.status === 200) {
                console.log("good boye") 
                //---------------------------------
                // WANT TO CLOSE LOGIN DIALOG HERE;
                //---------------------------------
            } else if (response.status === 401) {
                console.log("naughty naughty")
                //---------------------------------
                // WANT TO DISPLAY SNACKBAR HERE
                //---------------------------------
            } else if (response.status === 502) {
                console.log("off it's hinges, innit")
            } else {
                console.log("sumat went bang")
            }
            return response.json();
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="modal-outer">
            <div className="modal-inner">
                <h3>Login</h3>
                <TextField
                />
                <br />
                <TextField
                />
                <Button variant="outlined" onClick={this.props.closePopup} color="secondary">
                    Cancel
                </Button>
                &nbsp;
                <Button variant="outlined" onClick={(event) => this.handleSubmit(event)} color="primary">
                    Login
                </Button>
            </div>
            </div>
        );
  }
}

export default LoginDialog
```

Can I call/make some kind of displaySnackbar method on the Snackbar component? How can I call methods or functions on functional components?

I'm having real trouble understanding how React fits together. I'm maninly a backend developer but I've used JQuery and other Javascript frameworks in the past.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In React, you can only display things inside of `render()`. This means that you need to include the snackbar component inside of your render. You can use conditional rendering to decide whether to display them or not. Usually this is done by some value in the component state. You should initialize a state flag to `false` in the constructor and then call `setState()` in your fetch response code to set it to `true`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) 

Just to clarify; is `render()`  automatically called again if I set the state of a flag in my `handleSubmit` function?


And how can I close my modal login window programmically? Is it a similar method? Like I said I can close the modal window by clicking on a link but how can I do this without manual intervention?

Comment: And how do I get the snackbar component to open without clicking on a link? The docs don't provide any clue on how to do this from another component only the component itself by calling a function. Is there anyway of doing something like `<CustomizedSnackbars open="true" />` as by default it isn't open.

Comment: I now get errors about ```Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): this is undefined``` I'm calling a new function called ToggleSnack from within the `handleSubmit` function like this `this.toggleSnack()`. I've bound this in the constructor with `this.toggleSnack = this.toggleSnack.bind(this);` All `toggleSnack` does is change a state variable. I've tried various combinations of just calling the ToggleShack function without `this.`, with and without binding and with and without parentheses all without joy.

Comment: @clg123 1. Yes, calling `setState()` automatically triggers a call to `render()` (eventually). 2. Yes, you can use a similar method to choose to show or not show (i.e. close) the modal login window. 3. Use conditional rendering to show (or not show) the snack bar. 4. For the errors you are now getting, you should post a new question with a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks. I've managed to get the snackbar to appear when I want it to - it turns out it's all in the binds. Thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction. If I can't get the modal window to close then I'll post a new question regarding just that as you suggested.

Comment: @clg123 can you please post the code or explanation as an answer?